# SIMD loop and C structures

Tags: c, simd

I am working on an algorithm running on a Analog Devices SHARC processor (ADSP-21371) that has SIMD instructions with one limitation:

The data fetched from the memory for ALU 2 must directly follow the data for ALU 1. In other words to perform a SIMD addition of `foo` and `bar` simultaniously one must declare foo and bar as follow:

```
#define foo foo[0]
#define bar bar[1]
int foobar[2];  

void main()
{
    enable_simd();
    foobar[0] += 42; // Does foo += 42 and bar += 42
}
```

This forces me to declare my structures as follow:

```
struct {
   int a[2];
   int b[2];
   int c[2]; 
} something;
```

instead of this:

```
struct {
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
} something[2];
```

Is there some tricks that allows using the latter form for my structure declaration?

Comment: SIMD *does* tend to work better with struct-of-array data than array-of-struct data.